# Is a matrix that are equal to the identity matrix symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, transpose

If we have a matrix lets say
$$
A=
\pmatrix{
2 & 2 & 6\\
4 & 3 & 7\\
9 & 2 & 2\\}
$$
and reduce the matrix to the identity matrix
$$
H=
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\}
$$
Can we then say that the matrix $A$ is symmetric because $H$ equals the identity matrix that are symmetric?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: symmetry doesn't preserve with elemental operations.

Comment: You can reduce $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ to the identity matrix; however, it is not symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Every invertible matrix reduces to the identity matrix. There are plenty of invertible matrices that aren't symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

A symmetric matrix is a square matrix A that satisfies $A=A^{T}$ when $A^{T}$ denotes the transpose of A, i.e $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$. Clearly the identity matrix is always symmetric. However as Luis said, symmetry doesn't preserve with elemental operations, and in fact $A=A^{T}$ is not true for your matrix A.